# Variável $_SESSION do PHP vazia

Tags: php

Estou com um problema no login. Gravo o ID do usuário numa variável de sessão, assim que ele se loga, mas essa variável está ficando vazia, alguém sabe o porque?

PHP

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $username = $_POST['name'];
 $password = $_POST['pwd'];

 include("conexao.php");
 mysql_select_db("mg", $conn) or print(mysql_error()); 

 $query = "SELECT id_usuario, nm_login, nm_senha, nm_nome, nm_sobrenome, nm_imagem FROM tbl_usuario WHERE nm_login='".$username."' AND nm_senha='".$password."'";

 $result = mysql_query($query,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
 $num_row = mysql_num_rows($result);
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
 if( $num_row >=1 ) {
   echo 'true';
   $_SESSION['usuario']=$row['id_usuario'];
   $_SESSION['login']=$row['nm_login'];
   $_SESSION['nome']=$row['nm_nome'];
   $_SESSION['sobrenome']=$row['nm_sobrenome'];
   $_SESSION['avatar']=$row['nm_imagem'];
 }
 else{
   echo 'false';
 }
?>
```

Nessa linha ela aparece vazia, se dou F5 ele carrega a variável

```
    if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
        echo "<li><a href='#' id='login-link'>Login</a></li>";
    };
```

Esta dando o erro

> **Notice: Undefined index: usuario**

Valeu

Comment: Uma coisa que você vai ouvir bastante aqui é que tua query está sujeita a SQL Injection e que pra fazer login nesse sistema não é necessário possuir usuário e senha válidos. Veja por favor: http://www.devmedia.com.br/sql-injection-em-ambientes-web/9733

Comment: Ainda não tratei SQL Injection. De qualquer forma, obrigado por me lembrar :)

Comment: `isset($_SESSION['usuario'])` não dispara erro tipo *Notice: Undefined index: usuario*. O erro pode não ser nesta linha.

Comment: A session do php esta funcionando pereitamente, mas parece que em algum ponto voce nao setou a index $_SESSION['usuario'] ou talvez tenha resetado, na linha com `echo 'true'` esta aparecendo a palavra true no seu navegador?

Comment: Olimon, esse echo 'true' é apenas usado no retorno pro jQuery: if(html=='true') {   document.form1.loading.style.visibility = "hidden";
$("#login-form").fadeOut("slow");
$("#background-on-popup").fadeOut("slow");
$("#perfil").fadeOut("fast");
$("#perfil").load("perfil.php");
$("#perfil").fadeIn("fast");
}

Comment: O estranho é que se tivesse perdido o valor da Session, dando o F5 ela não seria carregada com o valor correto.

Comment: @PapaCharlie Papa Charlie, o erro está nessa linha:    
echo $sql1 = "SELECT nm_imagem FROM tbl_usuario WHERE id_usuario =".$_SESSION['usuario'];
Aparentemente porque a $_SESSION['usuario'] está vazia

Comment: Acho que descobri o que está acontecendo. Quando o usuário loga, apenas é carregado um arquivo php dentro de uma DIV no topo, só que esse topo já havia sido carregado anteriormente sem valor na Session, entenderam?

Answer (score 1):

Isso pode ocorrer se por algum motivo você está recriando a sua sessão a cada post/submit/refresh.

Caso isso aconteça, ele vai perder os valores da session antiga.

Dê uma olhada, se o código session_start() não está rodando a cada interação da página.

Tente usar um singleton na session para evitar esse problema:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
```

Comment: Todos os lugares do código que tem session_start(), já estavam conforme você comentou
    if(!isset($_SESSION)){
        session_start();
    }
Mas ainda assim continua carregando VAZIO

Comment: Eu dei uma pesquisada sobre erros parecido, no stackoverflow americano, um usuário resolveu o mesmo problema, separando o codigo do botão de logout.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411588/php-session-lost-after-refreshing-page

Comment: Outra sugestão que encontrei é usar o Outra sugestão que encontrei é usar o **session_regenerate_id()** e o **session_write_close()**

Comment: nunca usei essa session_regenerate_id(), vou dar uma pesquisada... Vlw