# Session vazia atualizando apenas DIV

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Fiz um login em PHP, onde valido os dados via Ajax e carrego uma página PHP para dentro de uma DIV, isso para não ter que dar o refresh na página inteira. Até ai tudo certo.

```
 <?php
 if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
 }

 $username = $_POST['name'];
 $password = $_POST['pwd'];
 $username_esc = addslashes($username);
 $password_esc = addslashes($password);

 include("conexao.php");
 mysql_select_db("mg", $conn) or print(mysql_error()); 

 $query = "SELECT id_usuario, nm_login, nm_senha, nm_nome, nm_sobrenome, nm_imagem FROM tbl_usuario WHERE nm_login='".$username_esc."' AND nm_senha='".$password_esc."'";

 $result = mysql_query($query,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
 $num_row = mysql_num_rows($result);
 $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
 if( $num_row >=1 ) {
   echo 'true';
   $_SESSION['usuario']=$row['id_usuario'];
   $_SESSION['login']=$row['nm_login'];
   $_SESSION['nome']=$row['nm_nome'];
   $_SESSION['sobrenome']=$row['nm_sobrenome'];
   $_SESSION['avatar']=$row['nm_imagem'];
 }
 else{
   echo 'false';
 }
?>
```

-

```
    $(document).on('click', '#login', function () {
    username=$("#username").val();
    if (username == "") {
        $("#add_erro_login").html("Digite o usu&aacute;rio cadastrado");
        $("#username").focus();
        return false;
    }

    password=$("#password").val();
    if (password == "") {
        $("#add_erro_login").html("Digite a senha cadastrada");
        $("#password").focus();
        return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login.php",
        data: "name="+username+"&pwd="+password,
        success: function(html)
        {
            if(html=='true')
            {
                document.form1.loading.style.visibility = "hidden";
                $("#login-form").fadeOut("slow");
                $("#background-on-popup").fadeOut("slow");
                $("#perfil").fadeOut("fast");
                $("#perfil").load("perfil.php");
                $("#perfil").fadeIn("fast");
            }
            else 
            {
                document.form1.loading.style.visibility = "hidden";
                $("#add_erro_login").html("Usu&aacute;rio ou Senha inv&aacute;lido");
            }
        },
        beforeSend:function()
        {
            document.form1.loading.style.visibility = "visible";
            $("#add_erro_login").html("");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

O problema está na hora de recuperar a $_SESSION['usuario'] no topo do site. Pois quando ele é carregado ela está vazia, uma vez que o usuário não está logado, e depois como atualizo apenas a DIV, ela continua vazia.

Teria como recupera essa variável sem ter que dar refresh na página toda?

Comment: Chegou a resolver sua pergunta anterior? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38590/vari%C3%A1vel-session-do-php-vazia

Comment: Não, por isso tentei explicar melhor

Comment: É que se o problema é o mesmo, você deve melhorar aquela pergunta, e não abrir uma nova...

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que criar um trigger em javascrip para atualizar a div.
Seria algo como

```
$( "#foo" ).on( "custom", function( event) {
  // Faz o ajax para ir em um php e retornar os valores da session
});
```

Então você faz a chamada da trigger no final do success  do ajax que prepara o login, algo parecido com?

```
$( "#foo").trigger( "custom", [ "Custom", "Event" ] );
```

Comment: vc manja qual seria esse ajax? To pesquisando aqui, mas ainda não encontrei nada parecido... Vlw

Comment: Cria um ajax igual você fez para o login, só que no arquivo .php você vai enviar via json os dados do usuario logado.

Comment: Entendi, depois do almoço vou fazer. 

Fiz um teste colocando a chamada no final do success e um alert na trigger só pra ver se realmente estava chamando e não apareceu nada...